# usb_modeswitch not switching

Tags: usb, modem

After I upgraded from kernel 2.6.18 to 3.5.3 modeswitch started not to work for me. Although lsusb shows my usb modem, usb_modeswitch does not switch it. My system information is like below. I ran lsusb, dmesg, usb-devices and usb_modeswitch their output is like below. usb_modeswitch instead of switching my modem it says "No devices in default mode found. Nothing to do. Bye.". Can you offer a solution?

```
Kernel: Linux 3.5.3
usb_modeswitch: 1.2.3-1
usb_modeswitch-data: 20120120-1
usbutils: 006-1
libusb: 1.0.8-0.1



root@localhost$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 029: ID 12d1:1446 Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. 



root@localhost$ dmesg
[70112.477080] usb 2-1.4: new high-speed USB device number 30 using ehci_hcd
[70112.567757] scsi49 : usb-storage 2-1.4:1.0
[70112.567842] scsi50 : usb-storage 2-1.4:1.1
[70113.571433] scsi 49:0:0:0: CD-ROM HUAWEI Mass Storage 2.31 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
[70113.572304] scsi 50:0:0:0: Direct-Access HUAWEI TF CARD Storage PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
[70113.574169] sr0: scsi-1 drive
[70113.574223] sr 49:0:0:0: Attached scsi CD-ROM sr0
[70113.574250] sr 49:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 5
[70113.574350] sd 50:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[70113.577173] sd 50:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk



root@localhost$ usb-devices
T: Bus=02 Lev=02 Prnt=02 Port=03 Cnt=01 Dev#= 30 Spd=480 MxCh= 0
D: Ver= 2.00 Cls=00(>ifc ) Sub=00 Prot=00 MxPS=64 #Cfgs= 1
P: Vendor=12d1 ProdID=1446 Rev=00.00
S: Manufacturer=Huawei Technologies
S: Product=HUAWEI Mobile
C: #Ifs= 2 Cfg#= 1 Atr=c0 MxPwr=500mA
I: If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 2 Cls=08(stor.) Sub=06 Prot=50 Driver=usb-storage
I: If#= 1 Alt= 0 #EPs= 2 Cls=08(stor.) Sub=06 Prot=50 Driver=usb-storage



root@localhost$ cat /etc/usb_modeswitch.d/12d1\:1446
# Huawei, newer modems

TargetVendor= 0x12d1
TargetProductList="1001,1406,140b,140c,1412,141b,1433,1436,14ac,1506"

MessageContent="55534243123456780000000000000011062000000100000000000000000000"



root@localhost$ usb_modeswitch -c /etc/usb_modeswitch.d/12d1:1446 -v 12d1 -p 1446 -W

* usb_modeswitch: handle USB devices with multiple modes
* Version 1.2.3 (C) Josua Dietze 2012
* Based on libusb0 (0.1.12 and above)

! PLEASE REPORT NEW CONFIGURATIONS !

DefaultVendor= 0x12d1
DefaultProduct= 0x1446
TargetVendor= 0x12d1
TargetProduct= not set
TargetClass= not set
TargetProductList="1001,1406,140b,140c,1412,141b,1433,1436,14ac,1506"

DetachStorageOnly=0
HuaweiMode=0
SierraMode=0
SonyMode=0
QisdaMode=0
GCTMode=0
KobilMode=0
SequansMode=0
MobileActionMode=0
CiscoMode=0
MessageEndpoint= not set
MessageContent="55534243123456780000000000000011062000000100000000000000000000"
NeedResponse=0
ResponseEndpoint= not set

InquireDevice enabled (default)
Success check disabled
System integration mode disabled


usb_set_debug: Setting debugging level to 15 (on)
usb_os_find_busses: Skipping non bus directory devices
usb_os_find_busses: Skipping non bus directory drivers
usb_os_find_busses: Skipping non bus directory uevent
usb_os_find_busses: Skipping non bus directory drivers_probe
usb_os_find_busses: Skipping non bus directory drivers_autoprobe
Looking for target devices ...
No devices in target mode or class found
Looking for default devices ...
No devices in default mode found. Nothing to do. Bye.
```

Thanks in advance.